# C++ function that conditionally returns different types

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm attempting to write a template function that will return different types based on a string that is passed in.

```
template<typename T>
T test(string type)
{
    int   integer   = 42;
    float floateger = 42.42;

    if (type == "int")
        return integer;
    if (type == "float")
        return floateger;
}

int main()
{

    int integer = test("int");

    cout << "INTEGER: " << integer << endl;
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'test(const char [4])

**How can I implement such a thing?**

---

My end goal is to write a function that will return objects of different classes depending on what string is passed into it.  I know this probably isn't the right approach at all.  What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Consider `boost::any`

Comment: Looks like you need polymorphism

Comment: As you realize maybe it is not the right approach you probably should have elaborated what you actually try to do - rather than focus on your approach of solving your problem (and how that could be done)?

Comment: Don't do that. You can't.

Comment: @NeilKirk Crawling before walking before running.

Comment: Say you call this: `cin >> str; x = test(str);`. What type `x` should have? How do you want your program to behave in this case?

Comment: It looks like I may need to use an abstract factory to achieve what I am going for.  I have no clue how to implement one so let the Googling begin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, at least not that way.

In order to be able to return different types you would have to first return by reference and second the possible returned types would have to inherit from the declared return type.

For example:

```
class Base {
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
};

Base& func(string type) {
     static Derived1 d1;
     static Derived2 d2;

     if( type == "Derived1" )
         return d1;
     if( type == "Derived2" )
         return d2;

     //etc
}
```

Comment: Okay, so now I've returned a derived class and stored it in a reference to the base class... Now how do I access members of the derived class through this reference?

Comment: Sigh. You don't. That's the gist of polymorphism. You only access members of the base class. The members themselves when they are virtual functions) know what to do.

Comment: You can directly use the interface of the `Base` class. Normally you would have virtual methods that are overridden in the derived classes to provide functionality. Otherwise if you need the derived type you could use `dynamic_cast` to convert the pointer/reference (if it's indeed referring to the expected type).

Comment: `dynamic_cast` sounds like it might be what I need.  I will look into that.

Answer (score 5):

A function always returns a value of the same type.

What you can do is to return a pointer to a common base class:

```
struct A {};

struct B : A {};

struct C : A {};

A* make(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "B")
        return new B;
    else if (s == "C")
        return new C;
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: It lets me do that, but once I use the function and return the base class I can't use it to access members of the selected non-base class.  I get "class <class> has no member named <member>" errors when trying to compile.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 You can't both have something that is "one-or-the-other" *and* know which one it is. It's the uncertainty principle of inheritance. If you care which of the types the return value is, you're looking for the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this.  Instead of returning the value, make it a second parameter:

```
template<class T>
void test(const char *var_type, T& ret) {
    int integer = 42;
    float f = 42.42;

    if (0 == strcmp(var_type, "int")) {
        ret = integer;
    } else if (0 == strcmp(var_type, "float")) {
        ret = f;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
int integer = 0;
float f = 0.0;
test((const char *) "int", integer);
printf("%d\n", integer);
test((const char *) "float", f);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Boost you could solve this by using boost::variant:

```
typedef boost::variant< int, float, YourSpecialDataType > MixedData;
```

And then have the method return this type:

```
MixedData test(std::string type) {
   int   integer   = 42;
   float floateger = 42.42;

   if (type == "int")
      return integer;
   if (type == "float")
      return floateger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in general to overload the returned value, for it would be impossible for the compiler to solve it. Imagine a statement like the following one:

```
your_overloaded_function();
```

You don't store the returned value in any variable, for you are not interested in it, so how could the compiler understand which function you want to invoke? It cannot, simply.

You can return a base class of a hierarchy, that is not an overloaded returned value indeed, but it let you to return different instances of different classes, thus getting something near to what you're trying to achieve.

Anyway, there are some tricks to get it explicitly. It follows a possible one using partial specialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct S { };

template<typename T>
struct S<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    T operator()() { return 42; }
};

template<typename T>
struct S<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
{
    T operator()() { return 42.42; }
};

int main()
{
    S<int> si;
    S<float> sf;
    int integer = si();
    float float_ = sf();
    cout << "INTEGER: " << integer << endl;
    cout << "FLOAT: " << float_ << endl;
}
```

That said, this is a snippet involving *integer* and *float* as from in your example.

Anyway, to do that what I think you want to do, you can rely as an example on well known patterns like the [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or the family of *creational patterns*, instead of relying on templates.

Comment: As you may have guessed I'm not the most experienced with C++,  I will look deeper into these patterns, but they tend to go way over my head... :(

Comment: no problem. be aware that the code above and the other pattern are different things, this code is not about an abstract factory.

Comment: Yes I know, it is interesting though, I've never seen anyone overload `operator()`.  There is so much I need to learn.

Comment: well, hoping this response is useful to you to start learning more. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`int integer = test<int>("int");`
works.

And you don't need to pass "int" as string, if the `<>` type
is int or float is detectable by code in the function.

PS: "floateger"?

Comment: Haha, I needed a longer name for a float and couldn't think of anything... And adding <int> gives me a warning: warning: converting to 'int' from 'float'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to achieve such functionality to return different types upon string parsing. (I assume that string is result of user input). C++ is strong typed language type so compiler must know exact return type. If string value is hard-coded you can change implementation to:

```
template<typename T>
T test()
{
    int   integer   = 42;
    float floateger = 42.42;

    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        return integer;
    else
        return floateger;
}

int main()
{

    int integer = test<int>();

    cout << "INTEGER: " << integer << endl;
}
```

Or if you are not limited to POD types look at @molbdnilo or @skyking answers.